# How to insert values into Custom Object between Two Times

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

I have Custom Object `Scheduler__c` which contains fields `StartTime,EndTime,T9,T930,T10,T1030,T11,T1130,T12,T1230..........T17(5PM)`.T9 to T17 are time slots for `30 minutes` and these are Number DataType holds value 0 or 1.

I created a `VF` page and it contains `2 SelectList` and values for these lists are `9,9:30,10,10:30.........5:00`.When user selects `9:30(SelectList)(Value is '2')` and `12:00(Another SelectList Value is '7')` the values i need to store for `T930,T10,T1030,T11,T1130,T12 is 1` and remaining `field values should be 0`.How do i achieve this.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could just brute force your way through with Apex.

```
integer startSelect = 2; // User has selected 9:30 in the first SelectList
integer stopSelect = 7; // User has selected 12:00 in the second SelectList

Scheduler__c sch = new Scheduler__c();
sch.T9__c = (startSelect <= 1 && stopSelect >= 1)?1:0;
sch.T930__c = (startSelect <= 2 && stopSelect >= 2)?1:0;
sch.T1030__c = (startSelect <= 3 && stopSelect >= 3)?1:0;
// ...
sch.T12__c = (startSelect <= 7 && stopSelect >= 7)?1:0;
// ...
```

Personally, I'd make these fields Boolean/checkboxes rather than numbers. However, I don't know what else you are doing with them.

Comment: Its working fine thank you @Daniel Ballinger .But so many if condition,is there any other way do it simple..?

Comment: You could create two DateTime fields to hold the values and ignore the Date component of them. Then you would only need to set two values.

Comment: Or create a method that takes the startSelect, stopSelect and threshold integer as parameters and applies the logic in one place.

Comment: You could create two DateTime fields to hold the values and ignore the Date component of them. Then you would only need to set two values.How can i do this...?the second approach i did.

Comment: Exactly that. Make two custom fields with the DataTime data type. One for the start time and one for the stop time. Then set the time component of each of these as required by the user selected start and stop date. Set the date component to some fixed value and ignore it.

Comment: Yes i have two custom fields for StartTime and EndTime,but how can i get the values and store the values 0 and 1 for all the fields as for my question..

Comment: That comes back to my original answer. My Datetime field suggestion was an alternative approach for storing the data.

Comment: No for storing i need all fields because i am performing other operations based on that.Thank you so much for including your valuable time into this.